# Reactjs - convert string to HTML

Tags: html, reactjs

I have one problem with my code. I get string like 
"1234",
and it wont render proper.
I will post code and picture, so you can see whats happening.

```
    var valuteArray = ["USD", "AUD", "BGN", "BRL", "CAD", "CHF", "CNY", "CZK", "DKK", "GBP", "HKD", "HRK", "HUF", "IDR", "ILS", "INR", "JPY", "KRW", "MXN", "MYR", "NOK", "NZD", "PHP", "PLN", "RON", "RUB", "SEK", "SGD", "THB", "TRY", "ZAR", "EUR"];

     class Valute extends Component {
      render(){
      var currencyOptions = "";
      valuteArray.forEach((valuta) => currencyOptions += '<option>' + valuta + '</option>')
          return(
            <select className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle col-md-3">
              <option hidden> Choose your currency </option>
              {currencyOptions}
            </select>
          );
         }
        }
```

and here is a picture from Chrome - Elements

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are treating them as a string, don't forgot we write `JSX`.

**[JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)**:

> Fundamentally, JSX just provides syntactic sugar for the 
>    `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)` function.

Write it like this:

```
var currencyOptions = [];
valuteArray.forEach(valuta => currencyOptions.push(<option key={valuta} value={valuta}>{valuta}</option>)
```

Or you can use **[#array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** directly:

```
<select className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle col-md-3">
  <option hidden> Choose your currency </option>
  {
    valuteArray.map(valuta => <option key={valuta} value={valuta}>{valuta}</option>)
  }
</select>
```

Also assign key to each dynamically created elements.